# Connection property has not been initialized c#

Tags: c#

im getting this when Execute non query .. 
calling to ExecuteNonQuery....

```
   clsConnection.ExecuteNonQuery("ADD_CUSTOMERS", CommandType.StoredProcedure, paramList);
```

exception pop up at `cmd.Connection.Open();`

this is the whole ExecuteNonQuery

```
 public static void ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, CommandType type, List<SqlParameter> paramList)




        try
        {
            DataAccess.clsConnection clsDB = new DataAccess.clsConnection();
            using (SqlConnection cn =clsDB.OpenCon())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd = CreateCommand(sql, type, paramList);
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = type;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
```

Comment: x / y when y is always 0 ..... divide by 0????

Comment: +1 to @DarrenDavies Why **are** you doing the divide by 0?

Comment: commnet the line cmd.Connection.Open(); You have already opened the connection. Try cmd.Connection = MainCon;

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - Although it is away from the OP's original question, this seems abit strange to me and thought I would point it out.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Agreed, I was going to point it out as well, until I saw you'd already done so.. (sorry, the comment was actually aimed at the OP, not you :))

Comment: like others said you need to assign your connection to the command object.Also you might think of placing the connectionstring in an config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't assign the connection object to the command

When the SqlCommand executes the query it needs an open connection. So the first step is to search its connection property to see if it has been initialized. The property is null and thus you get the error

Simply fix it with

```
 cmd.Connection = MainCon;
```

Of course, you have already opened the connection and thus you don't need the line

```
 cmd.Connection.Open();
```

Said that, I really suggest you to avoid to keep a global connection object in that way. It is better for the performance and for the impact on the system resources used by your program to change that **OpenCon** to return the connection opened and use the using statement to free the resource when no more needed

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class clsConnection
    {
        public SqlConnection OpenCon()
        {           
                DBN = "PMS";
                SERVER = "server-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";
                USER = "SA";
                PWD = "Sysadmin123";

                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=" + DBN + ";Data Source=" + SERVER + "; User id =" + USER + "; Password =" + PWD + ";CONNECT Timeout=10");
                .....
                cn.Open();                   
                return cn;

        }        

    }
}
```

So your code that use the connection could be changed to

```
try
{
   DataAccess.clsConnection clsDB = new DataAccess.clsConnection();
   using(SqlConnection cn = clsDB.OpenCon())
   {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd = CreateCommand(sql, type, paramList);
       cmd.Connection = cn;
       cmd.CommandType = type;
       cmd.CommandText = sql;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Here the closing braces closes and disposes the connection freeing the resources used
    // also in case of exceptions 
    }  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ....
}
```

**EDIT**: Seeing your comment below, added more context to the method OpenCon. I strongly suggest you to change your code and take advantage of the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: whern enter cmd.Connection = MainCon;..error pop up.. An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
.. this is the connection have use to the whole system. im doing only one part. Thanks anyway for that Suggestion.it will help me in Future

Comment: If the class that contains the OpenCon is not the same one where you build the command then you need to instantiate an object of that class to be able to use methods from that class. (For example `Dim clsCon = new DataAccess.clsConnection` and then clsCon.OpenCon()`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' got this error.. when do this (Check the main question)

Comment: OpenCon should return the connection object

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the connection to the Command

```
cmd = CreateCommand(sql, type, paramList);
cmd.Connection = MainCon;
```

Comment: i tried and got this error.
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DataAccess.clsConnection.MainCon'

Comment: You have a problem with your design. May be you can post your DataAccess class code...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Connection Timeout` instead of `Connect Timeout`

Comment: `Connect Timeout` is a valid value there, and he does not appear to be getting any errors regarding the connection string, anyway.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I stand corrected. Just never used this keyword before

Comment: Understandable; I had to look it up myself to verify it!

Answer (score 0):

And I would recommend using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder!

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "server-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";
builder.InitialCatalog = "PMS";
builder.UserID = "SA";
builder.Password = "Sysadmin123";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "ADD_CUSTOMERS";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```